# kotlin coroutine distinctUntilChanged work incorrect with room

Tags: android, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have table `Stories` in my android local db.
The problem:
When I set `story.isSeen = true` and save it to local db, I get obsevable data in `distinctUntilChanged { old, new -> }` but value of `old` and `new` olways same.
`old[n].isSeen` is true, anthough it was false.

 `distinctUntilChanged()` also didn't work.

 Story structure:

```
@Keep
@Entity(tableName = "stories")
@Parcelize
data class Story (
    @PrimaryKey
    var id: Int,
    var name: String,
    var iconName: String,
    var isAttached: Boolean = false,
    var lastShownPosition: Int,
    var isSeen: Boolean = false,

    @TypeConverters(DateConverter::class)
    var expiresAt: Date,

    @TypeConverters(DateConverter::class)
    var createdAt: Date,

    @TypeConverters(StoryItemsConverter::class)
    var items: List<StoryItem>
): Parcelable
```

I use Flow to observe data:

```
    @Query("SELECT * FROM stories WHERE :today <= expiresAt LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset ")
    fun getStories(today: Long, limit: Int = -1, offset: Int = 0): Flow<MutableList<Story>>
```

And how I observe them:

```
    suspend fun getStories(sync: Boolean = false, params: JSONObject = defaultStoriesQueryParams) {
        val today = System.currentTimeMillis()

        storiesDao.getStories(today).distinctUntilChanged { old, new ->
            if (new.size != old.size) return@distinctUntilChanged false
            for (i in 0..new.size) {
                if (old[i].isSeen != new[i].isSeen) return@distinctUntilChanged false
            }
            return@distinctUntilChanged true
        }.collect { newData ->

            if (newData.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                _storiesFlow.emit(StoriesResource.Loading())

                val remoteData = syncStories(params)
                when {
                    remoteData == null -> _storiesFlow.emit(StoriesResource.Error("Request error"))
                    remoteData.code != 200 -> _storiesFlow.emit(StoriesResource.Error(remoteData.message))
                    remoteData.code == 200 && remoteData.payload.isNullOrEmpty() -> _storiesFlow.emit(StoriesResource.Empty())
                }
            } else {
                _storiesFlow.emit(StoriesResource.Data(newData))
            }
        }
    }
```

How I save changes:

```
fun update(story: Story) {
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            storiesDao.updateStories(story)
        }
    }
```

P.S. Sorry for my english, if did mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved. The room holds in cache the last request object reference. Also this reference goes to view where object was been changed. This why I compare changed object with changed object.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).